# Firebase. Token doesn't generate after changing of signings (from personal to developer signing)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I used firebase for sending push-notification on IOS in XCode. In configurations, I used my simple AppleID (without developer license)

When writing such code I get Token:

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
print("token = \(Messaging.messaging().fcmToken)")
```

After that in the configuration, I changed my signing to the developer license. And now my Token always equals nil.

Could you please tell what is the reason why Token doesn't generate after changing of signings?

I also tried `pod update` and it didn't help.

Comment: Did you set up the FCM configurations from the firebase console and update the settings in your apple developer account?

Comment: No, I’ve used personal apple account without developer license, than in Xcode configuration I switched my account to the developer one and afterwards I don’t get the Token